# How can I match (mysql) rows by one field and also another field that does not match

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have a MySQL table with 4 fields:

```
ID | ONE | TWO | THREE
```

I need to do a query that, in the end result, will show two rows.  I need field 'ONE' to match. Both say 'widget'.

Then, field 'TWO' of one row should match 'MFG' and the other to be anything except 'MFG'.  For example:

```
ID | ONE | TWO | THREE
-----------------------
1  | WID | MFG | sthg
2  | WID | STR | stes
```

OK, maybe this will help..

This is the statement I have so far.

```
SELECT * 
FROM cs_coupons 
WHERE brand='Zantac'
  AND product='Heartburn Relief 24ct +'
  AND type='MFG'

 UNION 

SELECT * 
FROM cs_coupons 
WHERE brand='Zantac'
  AND product='Heartburn Relief 24ct +'
  AND type != 'MFG'
```

What I need to do is sort through all the rows checking each brand for these matches.

Comment: Sounds like your second condition is rather pointless. In pseudo SQL terms, you're looking for *all rows WHERE column ONE matches "WID" AND column TWO matches ("MFG" OR NOT "MFG")*. Matching *"MFG"* ***or anything else*** basically means *"anything"*.

Comment: I need to make sure one matches MFG and the other is anything but MFG.

Comment: How do you determine which single MFG is returned?  Assuming their are duplicates

Comment: There are duplicates. hundreds and sometimes thousands.

Answer (score 2):

```
((SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ONE='WID' AND TWO='MFG' LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ONE='WID' AND TWO != 'MFG' LIMIT 1) );
```

first query returns one record with WIG & MFG, second query returns one record with WIG & !MFG. There you go.

But I think most probably you're misconstructing the scheme. You won't be sure that which record will be chosen if there are more than one records with WIG & MFG.

Comment: Thank you, Ahmet. There are going to be hundreds of rows that will have more than WID. My goal is to find rows that match field ONE and make sure that field TWO does not match. So, you are correct. How could I match field ONE and make sure one of the rows in field TWO match MFG and doesn't. Thank you in advance.

Comment: sry, I ment * and the other does not match.

Comment: sorry, I could not understand your second limitation in the comment above. maybe somebody can understand and help you. my advice is you must read a book about SQL. SQL worths only 30-40 pages but in the end you'll be really good at it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM cs_coupons
WHERE ID IN (
  SELECT MIN(ID) AS ID
  FROM cs_coupons 
  WHERE type='MFG'
  GROUP BY brand, product

  UNION ALL

  SELECT (MIN(ID) AS ID
  FROM cs_coupons 
  WHERE type != 'MFG'
  GROUP BY brand, product
) x
ORDER BY brand, product, type = 'MFG' DESC
```

?